# non static method can't be reference from static context

Tags: java

Whenever I try to call a method in the main it gives me the error

> non static method can't be reference from s static context

I tried creating objects in the main and send them as parameter to the method but it doesn't work either.

Comment: And your question is? Furthermore, this is a fairly basic problem - start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/. And please provide the code

Comment: Search on Google, and start with a good tutorial. Oracle tutorial will be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main` is a static method. `public static void main(String[] args)`.

From static method or block any other static method as well static instance's are accessible. And if you ant to access non static method or instance you have to create object and access through the reference.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        print();// static method call
        Test test = new Test();
        test.print();// non static method call
    }
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello non static");
    }
    public static void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello static");
    }
}
```

Comment: Might want to expand on that

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.print();
    }
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need an **instance of your class** to **access(invoke) non-static methods** from **static methods**. non-static methods or instance methods are confined to an insatnce of a class.

Below is the simple example which describes it:

```
class Test {
public void nonStaticMethod() {
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
Test t = new Test(); //you need to create an instance of class Test to access non-static methods from static metho
t.nonStaticMethod();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Regular methods are instantiated when an object is created, but that isn't required for `static` methods. Saying as you're in a `static` method, there's no guarantee the non-static method has been instantiated (i.e. there may be no `Object` created), so the compiler doesn't allow it.